# Loop and wait batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, wait

I have made a batch script with a start /wait and a check if it's run again. If not go to shut down script if it runs again wait again but it not work it starts the program over and over.

Can someone tell me what to do?

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -bigpicture
timeout /t 10 > nul
tasklist | find /I "Steam"
if errorlevel 1 (
    START C:\Scripts\shutdown.vbs
) else (
    GOTO START
)
EXIT
```

Comment: `find` will set `errorlevel` to `0` if found, 1 or greater otherwise. Your code will run the shutdown if `steam` is not found, restart otherwise. ?? Shouldn't you first check for the process and shout it down if it exists *then* restart it? Really - your description of what you want to do is confusing.

Comment: The problem is when steam updates it wil close. Then it wait if it comes back af update if not shutdown else wait again. But now it wil loop for ever. But it must wait again

Comment: @Pascal, it is clear that you're starting `steam.exe` in `bigpicture` mode but from that point everything becomes unclear. You seem to want to shutdown the PC or start steam again, but we have no idea why or under which scenarios you wish to do so. I'm assuming, upon starting, a non bypassable update check is performed and if found the program closes, updates and reopens, but not in `bigpicture` mode; and that this is what you're wanting to detect. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49598413/edit) your question to better explain your problem and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: BTW, the command you probably need is, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -start steam://open/bigpicture`.

Comment: This is the command i use for booting directly in steam steamos mode and bigpicture.  It waits if i expediently close it then it will run the shutdownscript or wait if steam is updating and came back and wait again else it shutdown. I use the command -steamos -bigpicture this works fine and makes the exit menu smaller with no options to go back to windows but you can close steam when close it will go to the shutdownscript but when updating to but i want him to go back to start when steam cames back from the update

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

call :START
if errorlevel 1 call :START
exit /b

:START
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -bigpicture
timeout /t 10 > nul
tasklist | find /i "Steam"
if not errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
start C:\Scripts\shutdown.vbs
exit /b 0
```

This will call `:START`. `exit /b` with a following integer will set an errorlevel of 0 or 1. If `:START` sets errorlevel 1, then a 2nd call is done to `:START`.

This eliminates the `goto :START` loop.

Comment: Thnx for the reaction i wil test this when i am home